# OpenJDK platform binary resources problem

Tags: android-studio

Any help with OpenJDK platform binary resources problem

I tried to reinstall android studio and my windows
tried to open new project and I faced the same problem I don't know why

[image]

Comment: This has already been asked 3 times on SO recently, none of which have been answered. Roll back Android Studio, and go complain on Google's issue tracker.

Comment: What do you mean by roll back AS? to which version @Zoe

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was about flutter, update It or uninstall it